# ActivePerl CPAN and .tshrc

Tags: perl, cpan, tcsh

I installed ActivePerl (5.24.3.1) on a Mac OS X and caused 'havoc' with CPAN installations. The new installs are separated from the "core CPAN.pms", in "sites/lib/".

Anyway I have stuck the following in my directory .cshrc

```
setenv PERL5LIB PERL5LIB:/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.24/lib:/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.24/site/lib
```

I made it up, but everything seems to work. Is it valid code?

Comment: Re "*I found that new installs are separated from the "core CPAN.pms", in a sneaky directory called "sites/lib/" (bizarre).*", Uh, that's normal. User-installed, vendor-installed and core modules should be installed in different directories, and "site" is a normal name for the user-installed modules. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30379902/589924).

Comment: You shouldn't have to tell Perl where to look for these. What's the output of `perl -le'print for @INC'` with `PERL5LIB` unset, and what's the output of `perl -V:'install(privlib|archlib|vendorlib|vendorarch|sitelib|sitearch)'`?

Comment: Yes you are right its not needed, the problem was the user access to "sites".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line correctly appends to the environment variable `PERL5LIB` in `tcsh`.

From `man tcsh` on my system

> setenv [name [value]]
>
> Without arguments, prints the names and values of all environment variables.  Given name, sets the environment variable name to value or, without value, to the null string.

An environment variable in `tcsh` can be set to a value that represents a list by separating entries with a colon (`:`). Thus saying `PERL5LIB:...` is a way to append to an existing value of `PERL5LIB`.

The `PERL5LIB`, as explained [in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#PERL5LIB), is

> A list of directories in which to look for Perl library files before looking in the standard library and the current directory. Any architecture-specific and version-specific directories, such as version/archname/, version/, or archname/ under the specified locations are automatically included if they exist, with this lookup done at interpreter startup time.

but note that the "*current directory*" is not searched for libraries any more, a security enhancement in modern Perl versions.

So your line is adding the `/usr/local/ActivePerl` locations to the defaults paths set up in your Perl version.

I can't tell how and why ActivePerl "*caused havoc with CPAN installations*" (?) on a Mac OS X. I presume that you had another Perl installed (by your mention of "*CPAN installantions*"), but I am confused as to which one you are using now, once that ActiveState is there (as well?).

Comment: Thanks! I'm using ActiveState's ActivePerl now (later version). The difficulty was the user installed CPAN modules are dumped here "/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.24/site/lib", which is a root ownership directory. I thought they would be here, "/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.24/lib" and I just couldn't figure why I was getting "permission denied" errors when running a script without 'sudo'. I misread the error output within cpan shell.

Comment: I guess "havoc" (computer) is probably better described as "angst" (me). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

**To summarise**, the output of @INC command line inquiry makes it clear that ActiveStates Perl automatically sees CPAN libs so `"setenv PERL5LIB PERL5LIB:....:...."` within .cshrc duplicates this as @ikegami identified.

The latest stable ActiveStates implementation of Perl works fine, the primary problem was the permission over the 'sites/lib' directory (OS X installation not Linux).

However, my coding app (BBEdit, version 12.6.1) does require PERL5LIB to be set within .cshrc before the "run" function will work. So @zdim response was useful in context. Thanks to both responders, appreciated.